# Using templates to make items of varying length stay on stack?

Tags: c++, templates

The situation is that I have an array of items, and the items have an array inside. However, I want to make the array inside of variable length at declaration time, yet resizable at compile time.

So I would want something like:

```
class2<16>[] = new class2<16>[2048*1024];
```

Or whatever. Hopefully you get the idea.

Obviously making it have fixed array inside is easy, but the problem is the array can be HUGE so I don't want to have 2048*1024 calls to new, so I definitely don't want class2 to call any new or delete methods.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you mean something like `template<size_t itemSize> struct A { A(size_t itemCount) {} };` ?

Comment: And having huge structures created on the stack won't cause problems?

Comment: It won't be on the stack. I agree using stack up can be a bigger problem. What I want is to have ONE allocation for entire array, but if the classes have their own allocation (dynamic) then this is not possible.

Comment: gf - I am not sure if that will do exactly what I want, I will have to ponder it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a template parameter for your internal array-size. For example:-

```
template<int siz>
class Item{
  int arr[siz];
};

int main() {
  Item<15> items[10];
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::tr1::array` (addition to standard library in C++0x) and `boost::array` already exist, taking two template parameters: the type and count of items:

```
std::tr1::array<int, 16> something;
```

You can have any number of those arrays at **run**-time with the std::vector container:

```
std::vector<std::tr1::array<int, 16> > lots_of_arrays(2048*1024);
```

Only one dynamic allocation involved here.